# How to create blank wordpress theme/page which contains one sentence?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a domain and a site I'm going to launch in the future. However, currently I want the website to be completely blank, with just two words in the middle, center of page - "Coming soon."

How do I accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a comingsoon.html file in your site root and then add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/comingsoon\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/comingsoon.html [R=307,L]
```

Idea taken from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/htaccess-maintenance-page-redirect)

Comment: Thank you Henry Wright. Since I don't know what a site root and .htaccess file is could you please explain.